# Table rownum returns 0 records if rownum is tested for value greater than 100

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join, oracle11g

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rownum not working with query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240192/rownum-not-working-with-query)

I am running some tests for how `rownum` works. Please could someone explain the output of the following queries - Specifically why the third query is returning 0 rows.

Query 1 - Returns 2456 rows

```
Select rownum, s.id, s.title, sv.version_id
from software s JOIN software_version sv on (s.id = sv.id);
```

Query 2 - Returns 100 rows

```
Select rownum, s.id, s.title, sv.version_id
from software s JOIN software_version sv on (s.id = sv.id)
where rownum between 1 and 100;
```

Query 3 - Returns 0 rows

```
Select rownum, s.id, s.title, sv.version_id
from software s JOIN software_version sv on (s.id = sv.id)
where rownum between 101 and 400;
```

Thanks

Comment: I think the Oracle docmentation does a perfectly good job explaining why this is the case:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

rownum is only evaluated AFTER the row is fetched and other predicates are evaluated. that is the key. so if you say
`select * from table where rownum >= 2;`

it can never work, as it works like

```
open cursor loop
  fetch row (rownum is evaluated as the last thing here)
    if fetched then rownum = rownum + 1
end cursor
```

if you request rownum starting from > 1 then its never true. to do pagination if you need to you have to code like

```
select *
  from (select rownum r, t.*
          from your query tables
         order by ..)
 where r>=101 
   and rownum <= 400
```

also read more here at [ask tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:62364503028143)