# Can a row be deleted by specifying ROWNUM in Oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete, rownum

I have some values as below:

```
MYSTRING
--------
Dharshan
Ramalingam
Devid
```

I can select the specific row value through below query

```
select * from ( select mystring , rownum rn  FROM teststring  )
```

where  rn = 2;

tell the way to delete this second row giving the row no and give me the brief explanation  . I have tried as below but its not work....

```
delete   from testring where rownum=2;
```

Comment: Please post your SQL as text, not images, and don't post in ALL CAPITALS!

Comment: Without using an `order by`, your `select` statement returns an arbitrary row.  A heap organized table is inherently unordered.  It would be perfectly valid for Oracle to return any of the three rows.  Which row is returned may change over time for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @JustinCave is spot on, and the conclusion is that it's not sensible to delete based on `rownum`, why do you need to? It's actually not a bad question!

Comment: `delete   from testring where rownum=2;` Your query will never delete any rows. A **ROWNUM** value is assigned to a row after it passes the **predicate phase** of the query but before the query does any sorting or aggregation. Also, a ROWNUM value is incremented only after it is assigned.

Comment: Your problem with rownum have an explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9240192/319875)

Answer (score 5):

```
select * from ( select mystring , rownum rn  FROM teststring  ) where  rn = 2;
```

Your query returns rows randomly without a specified order. A **heap-organized table** is a table with rows stored in **no particular order**. This is a **standard Oracle table**.

From Oracle [**documentation**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2171079),

> Without an order_by_clause, no guarantee exists that the same query executed more than once will retrieve rows in the same order.

```
delete from testring where rownum=2;
```

Your above query shows you do not understand [**how ROWNUM works**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321483/how-rownum-works-in-pagination-query/30321788#30321788).

**Your query will never delete any rows.**

A **ROWNUM** value is assigned to a row after it passes the **predicate phase** of the query but before the query does any sorting or aggregation. Also, a ROWNUM value is incremented only after it is assigned, which is why the following query will never return a row:

```
select * 
  from t 
 where ROWNUM = 2;
```

Because `ROWNUM = 2` is not true for the first row, `ROWNUM` does not advance to 2. Hence, no `ROWNUM` value ever gets to be greater than 1.

**How to correctly use ROWNUM:**

As you wanted to select a row based on ROWNUM, you could do something like pagination:

```
SQL> SELECT empno
  2  FROM
  3    (SELECT empno, sal, ROWNUM AS rnum FROM
  4      ( SELECT empno, sal FROM emp ORDER BY sal
  5      )
  6    )
  7  WHERE rnum =2;

     EMPNO
----------
      7900
```

It happens in three levels:

- Innermost sub-query first sorts the rows based on the **ORDER BY** clause.
- In second level, the sub-query assigns **ROWNUM**
- The outermost query filters the rows based on the ROWNUM given by inner query which is no more a pseudo-column but the sub-query resultset.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to delete all rows except one(just for understanding how the rownum works):

```
delete 
from table 
where rowid in (select rwid 
                from (select rownum as rn, rwid
                      from( select rowid as rwid from table)
                      order by rwid)
                where rn > 1);
```

or, more simpler:

```
delete from table
where rowid <> (select rowid from table where rownum = 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rownum is a pseudocolumn. 
The rownum is not assigned permanently to the row. It means you can't build your query based on this criteria.

You should instead delete your row with

`delete from teststring where mystring = 'RAMALINGAM';`

Comment: just i want to use rownum. Just think i want to delete all the rows which is greater than 2.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this Query and it's working fine.

```
DELETE FROM NG_USR_0_CLIENT_GRID_NEW WHERE rowid IN
( SELECT rowid FROM
  (
      SELECT wi_name, relationship, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rowid DESC) RN
      FROM NG_USR_0_CLIENT_GRID_NEW
      WHERE wi_name = 'NB-0000001385-Process'
  )
  WHERE RN=2
);
```

Please suggest that can we improve it's performance.
Any comment is appreciated.