# How to delete data from SQL except one row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some rows in table with the same `number`.

How to delete all rows except one row?

I mean this:

```
 number
1 2
2 2
3 2
4 2
```

So, I need to delete all rows where number = 2, but leave only one row, for example: `1 2`

Comment: Are there no other columns, just number?

Comment: No, there are any columns

Comment: Maybe you can get some useful information from this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33626927/can-a-row-be-deleted-by-specifying-rownum-in-oracle-11g

Comment: Just to verify - you don't have 2 columns? the left column in your example is not a real column?

Comment: People - test your  code!

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Some people may be using cell phones.  Actually, delete queries don't come up very often on SO, hence so many shoddy answers (mine included).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I can certainly relate to that :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delete t from t inner join t t2 on t2.number = t.number and t2.id < t.id
```

Comment: This query assumes that the `id` column will never have duplicates for a given `number` value.

Answer (score 1):

First, what is the real name of the table? It's not really named `t`, is it?  Let's assume it's named `MyTable`.
Second, Is the first column the primary Key? If so, then

```
Delete from MyTable t 
where PK !=
    (Select Min(PK) from MyTable
     where number = t.number)
```

NOTE: (this should be obvious) Please correct for whatever MySQL syntactical requirements demand for Deletes with subqueries.

Comment: Error Code xxxx: Comment contains no useful information

Comment: This is an opportunity to improve your comment and make it useful. Would you like a lesson in communication?

Comment: After adding the missing `from` we're getting a new error code - `Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 't' for update in FROM clause`. I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Actually, no, it is not.  this must be a syntactical requirement of MySQL (which I do not have),  and the error message is certainly not informative either, Neither the main SQL statement query, nor the subquery in my SQL is an update query. The other SQL is a Delete, and the subquery is a Select. Both reference table `t`. Which reference is the error message referring to?

Comment: I interperate this as - The deleted ("updated") table can't be referenced in the `from` of the sub-query.

Comment: then `t` is obviously not the name of the table. see edited answer. the table needs to be aliased so that the subquery's Where clause predicate can reference both the `number` attribute in the subquery reference to the table and the `number` attribute of the outer query table.

Comment: in a subquery, references toattributes (columns) are assumed to be in tables in that subquery (if they exist) and the query processor will only look in the outer query if it cannot find a column with that name on one of the tables referenced in the subquery. So in my answer, `...where number = t.number ...` is, effectively, the same as  `...where myTable.number = t.number ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE (number2 = 2)
    AND (number1 <> 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will delete every row except 1st row

```
delete from table_name t1 
where pk_col not in (select pk_col from table_name where number = t1.number limit 1)
```

Assumption
    `pk_col` = primary key col

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax

Answer (score 0):

`delete from t where number=.. and pk > (select min(pk) from t)`

Comment: Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 't' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we Have 2 columns in table tb1:

```
ID   Name
1    Akshay
2    Akshay 
3    Akshay
```

In this I want to delete every row except the one with ID 2,

So I'll write the SQL statement as:

```
delete from tb1 where ID NOT LIKE 2
```

this will delete evey row except the second row.

Hope this helps.